# Supermicro NVME ports - how to use?

Tags: supermicro, nvme

So, my supermicro X11 Dai-N has 8 pci-e lanes routed to two dedicated nvme ports. I just can’t figure out how to connect my nvme harddisks to them.
What’s the name of this port specification? Is there some special cable required? If so, what’s the name of this cable and where do I get it?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I guess that's documented in the mainboard manual.

Comment: unfortunately no - in the mainboard manual it's only documented that these are ports for NVME disks and that each has 4 pci-e lanes routed to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the JNVME1 and JVNME2 connectors. You need a cable like [SuperMicro OCuLink](https://store.supermicro.com/supermicro-55cm-oculink-to-u-2-pcie-with-power-cable-cbl-sast-0956.html), or some other from [this list](https://store.supermicro.com/cable/sas-sata/oculink.html) to attach devices. The only M.2 NVMe port on your board is here

[image]

Comment: hmmm, but my SSDs are M.2 not U.2 - is there such a cable for M.2?

Comment: Check the edit.

Comment: So it seems there exists no cable from OcuLink o M.2?

Comment: Not from SuperMicro. There are some 3rd party ones I think, but no idea if they work. As I said, you have one M.2 port to use. Or you can use U.2 SSDs with the appropriate cables.

Answer (score 0):

They maynot be for hard discs but for U.2 ports - in which case you need special cables that plug into those ports and connect to the case' U.2 ports. That is what I run mine though in my EPYC servers - the case (also from supermicro) has 2 x U.2 ports for 2.5" NVME hard discs.

Comment: if I understand correctly, U.2 is a port definition in itself, so it would be an SATA shaped port if it was U.2

Comment: I had seen these ports.. This is esata, used mostly for servers while connecting high memory hard disks starts with a range of 10TB ~...!

Comment: Ah, no - if those are NVMe they are per definition not eSATA as eSATA does NOT push through 4 PCIe with NVME protocol. U.2 is a form factor and it is NOT SATA shaped - it is basically NVME in 2.5" form factor and special style connector able to handle NVMe in a hot swap form factor (which M.2 is not).